# Set expected x values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like for my time series plot to render `0` when an expected value is missing from the data set.

```
s1 <- data.frame(x=c('00:00', '01:00', '02:00'), y=c(1,2,3), sample='s1')
s2 <- data.frame(x=c('00:00', '03:00'), y=c(1,3), sample='s2')
s3 <- data.frame(x=c('00:00', '01:00', '02:00'), y=c(1,0,3), sample='s3')
mydata <- rbind(s1,s2,s3)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y, group=sample)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ sample)
```

For instance, in the set above hour `02:00` is missing from `s2`. I would like for `geom_line` to touch `0` between `00:00` and `03:00`, rather than connecting `00:00` and `03:00`. See `s3`.

Is this possible to do in ggplot? An other approach?

Thanks much

Comment: I think you need to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what @Roman meant...

```
# create template (df) with all possible x and sample
x  <- unique(mydata$x)    
df <- data.frame(x=rep(x,3),sample=rep(unique(mydata$sample),each=length(x)))
# merge actual data into template
df <- merge(df,mydata,by=c("x","sample"),all.x=T)
# set NA's to 0
df[is.na(df$y),]$y <- 0
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=sample)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ sample)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great. Thanks for the suggestion. I like the template df solution.